# Setting a parameter in TeamCity and checking the value after setting it

Tags: powershell, teamcity

After setting a parameter in using the

```
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='%env.VERSION_CODE%' value='$increment']"
```

If we check the value of %env.VERSION_CODE%,

```
echo %env.VERSION_CODE%
```

it is same as before setting the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the parameter is defined in Parameters on the Build Configurations.
2. Changing a parameter does not change it in the current step. If you echo in the same step, it will yield the old or no value. That is why I always use an extra step just for setting such parameters.

Comment: Pointing out: The second sentence is the most important one: "in the next step". Changing a parameter does not change it in the current step. If you echo in the same step, it will yield the old or no value. That is why I always use an extra step just for setting such parameters.